Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) at <Jasmine>
I am getting following error when ran the unit tests in pipeline for an angular app.


Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
        at <Jasmine>



This error occurs in the following unit test


  it('unit test description', (done) => {
        inject([HttpClient], (http: HttpClient) => {
            // Arrange
            const e1 = http.get('/base/src/assets/e1.json');
            const e2 = http.get('/base/src/assets/e2.json');
            expect(e1).toBe(e2);
            done();
        })();
    });



But when ran the same in local system dont see any issues. It works fine. All the tests pass without any issue.
Node version: v16.20.2
NPM version: 8.19.4
Package.json is


{
  "name": "abc",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "abc",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "update": "npm update --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/",
    "audit": "npm audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "build:dev": "ng build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@amplitude/analytics-browser": "~1.3.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~15.2.9",
    "@azure/storage-blob": "~10.5.0",
    "@jaames/iro": "~5.5.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "~15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "~15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "~15.4.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~7.0.0",
    "class-transformer": "~0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "~0.14.0",
    "d3": "~7.9.0",
    "file-saver": "~2.0.5",
    "jwt-decode": "~3.1.2",
    "lodash": "~4.17.21",
    "moment": "~2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "~0.5.43",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "~6.6.7",
    "sha.js": "~2.4.11",
    "typescript-collections": "~1.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.2.8",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~15.2.9",
    "@types/bingmaps": "7.0.20",
    "@types/d3": "~7.4.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "~2.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.4",
    "@types/lodash": "~4.14.195",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "~0.5.30",
    "@types/node": "~20.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~5.43.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~5.43.0",
    "codelyzer": "~6.0.2",
    "concurrently": "~7.4.0",
    "eslint": "~8.28.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.4.0",
    "jasmine-expect": "~5.0.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "~0.9.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.13",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5"
  }
}



Following is the karma.config.json


module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '../',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-coverage'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('karma-junit-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser,
            jasmine: {
                random: false,
            },
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
            reports: ['lcov', 'json', 'cobertura'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
        },
        reporters: ['coverage-istanbul', 'progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
        junitReporter: {
            outputDir: '',
            outputFile: 'abc.xml',
        },
        files: [
            {
                pattern: 'src/assets/**/*.json',
                watched: true,
                served: true,
                included: false,
            },
        ],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
        captureTimeout: 100000,
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000,
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 100000,
        flags: ['--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox'],
        singleRun: true,
    });
};



Any one facing the same issue?
Stuck with this issue from few days.

you seem to have shown all the setup, but forgotten the actual code, by the way, that karma.config.json isn't JSON, it's javascript - maybe that's the problem?

@Jaromanda X
Thats not the issue. Issue is something else related to build agent configuration. But I am not able figure it out.

you seem to have shown all the setup, but forgotten the actual code

@JaromandaX I have updated the description with the code block where I am facing issue.
